# bubble sort printing garbage values

Tags: c

I was curious on bubble sorting so I have made a function that takes user input and than stores the values in the posititons of an array but it keeps printing out some garbage value.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void sort(int*z);
void swap(int* element1Ptr,int* element2Ptr);

int main(void)
{  
    int number[10];  
    int input;  
    int* sorting;  

    sorting = number;
    printf("Please enter a number less than 10 digits long");
    scanf_s("%d", &input);
    for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        number[9-i]=input%10;
        input/=10;
    }
    printf("\n");
    sort(sorting);
    printf("%d\n",number[0]);
}
```

do I have the bubble soriting code wrong or am I passing the wrong variable?

```
void sort(int* z)
{
    int pass; /* pass counter */  
    int j; /* comparison counter */  

    /* loop to control passes */  
    for ( pass = 0; pass < 11; pass++ ) 
    {
        /* loop to control comparisons during each pass */
        for ( j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
        {
             /* swap adjacent elements if they are out of order */
             if ( z[ j ] > z[ j + 1 ] ) 
             {
                 swap( &z[ j ], &z[ j + 1 ] );
             } /* end if */
        } /* end inner for */
    } /* end outer for */
}/* end function bubbleSort */

void swap(int* element1Ptr,int* element2Ptr)
{
    int hold = *element1Ptr;
    *element1Ptr = *element2Ptr;
    *element2Ptr = hold;  
} /* end function swap */
```

Comment: You need to learn to debug: http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/debug.php

Comment: found the problem just after I posted this had nothing to do with the bubble sort it was in my main() function

Comment: @Footsure add answer below your own or delete the answer. What is the error?

Comment: @Footsure As GrijeshChuhan said, add your solution to this problem as an Answer or delete the question. As it stands it is not useful to anyone.

Comment: I just finisher adding the code that is what I did to fix it

Answer (score 1):

The error I was having I was trying to print the first value in the array and that value would always be `0` if you didn't have a `10` digit number:

```
 printf("%d\n", number[0]);
```

should read

```
 printf("%d\n", number[9]);
```

and the loop I had bult to place the values in was placing them in the wrong spot so I fixed it like so

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
     number[i] = input % 10;
     input /= 10;
}
```

that is all I changed and it worked fine.

Comment: Ok anyways I have some suggestions (1) you don't need `sorting` pointer, just pass base address of `number` array (increases bug chances if suppose you forget to initialize `sorting`) (2) You loop runs more times then required by standard bubble sorting algo for exmaple check [this code](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-bubble-sort) so correct loop breaking condition. (3) you can further improve code by using a flag in `if()` block  that means if no swamping required in some pass then return from sort function. [check wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: Additionally for codding style: always keep space after `;` and `,` in code, Also an expression like `number[i]=input%10;` should be written as `number[i] = input % 10;` that make code more readable. -- check my edit in your answer.

Comment: alright I am fairly new to posting on here as well as coding.

Comment: Yes that why I inform you. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your number input code is a bit funky. Instead of entering a single long number and then using %10 to get the value of each digit, why not enter a set of 10 numbers?

```
for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
{
    scanf_s("%d", &input);
    number[i]=input;
}
```

Comment: it would work that way I just wanted to make it so you didnt have to press enter each time.

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort should be

```
for ( pass = array_length - 2; pass >= 0; pass-- ) 
{
    for ( j = 0; j <= pass; j++ )
    {
       compare_and_swap(& z[j], & z[j + 1]);
    }

    // at this point in the code, you are guaranteed that 
    // every element beyond the index of pass is in the final
    // correct location in the array

    // so if you input array was {9, 8, 7, 6, 5}
    // and pass = 2
    // then elements 3 and 4 are correct here:
    // {*, *, *, 8, 9}
}

void compare_and_swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    if (*a > *b)
    {
        int temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = temp;
    }
}
```